# Where is Sitecore Form Database accessed from?

Tags: sitecore-forms

We have requirement to create custom table in Sitecore on publishing any 
Sitecore forms.With Sitecore 9 , all forms related data stored in seperate Form database.
So is Sitecore Form Database common between CM and CD server just like core ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form database is accessed by Content Management and Content Deliveries server.

[image]

More information you can find here: https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/architecture-and-roles/roles/xm/storage-roles/forms-database.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the forms database is directly accessed through the CD servers. There is no publishing on the forms database.